# Store result of Google Maps geocode function

Tags: google-maps, geocode

I want to retrieve and store the result of Google Maps API function `geocode()` in order to use it later.
I have put the code below on an `OnClick` event to reverse geocode the address of the point clicked on the map.

The problem is that it always contains the value of the previous point clicked.
Example: the first time I click it is 'undefined', 2nd time it is the address of the point I clicked before and so on.

```
var address ;


my_listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   codeLatLng(event.latLng);
});

function codeLatLng(mylatLng) {
    
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = mylatLng;

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            if (results[1]) 
            {
                address = results[1].formatted_address;
            }
        }
    });

    alert(address);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will move `alert`, inside of callback, you will see the new address:

```
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
        if (results[1]) 
        {
            address = results[1].formatted_address;
            alert(address);   //moved here
        }//   ^
    }//       |
});//         |  
//-------------
```

Geocoding process is *asyncronous*, so in this case:

```
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    //We be called after `alert(address);`
});
alert(address);
```

`alert` will be executed before the geocoding data will be recieved from server and callback `function(results, status){}` will be called.

Comment: And how can i store the `address` value so i can use it in other functions?

Comment: @SportBilly You can use it, only after the data is recevied from server. That means you need to call your function( that needs to perform some stuff on address) inside the `function(results, status){}` callback.

Comment: Thanks, but i do not want to call a function inside the geocode function.I want to call a function that shows the result.

Comment: @SportBilly After the `address = results[1].formatted_address;` line, write code,that shows the `address`.What's the problem?

Comment: I want the `address` variable to be accessible to more than one functions and they are not necessarily called right after the `geocode` function.

Comment: @SportBilly Then the execution of those functions must be prolonged untill `address` will be received.Use queues, booleans, temporary variables, etc...

Comment: @SportBilly, seconding what Engineer says.  Create a global variable which gets updated with the address.  The other functions will all have access to it, and may want to check it has length or whatever in case they get executed before the geocode function is complete