# js function is acting weird

Tags: javascript, html, submit

i have this logic: user gives his adres in the form, i will take this addres and in the submit function i will get the lat and long of this adres and save this into hidden input fields in the form and then submit the form with those lat and long inside.

my js function:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function geocodeme(adr) {
    var address = adr;

    geocoder.geocode(
        {'address': address}, 
        function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                //alert(latitude + ' - ' + longitude);
                $('#lat').val(latitude);
                $('#long').val(longitude);
            } 
        }
    ); 
}

function submitme(){
    var adres = str + '+' + hnr + '+' + plz + '+' + stadt + '+' + land;
    var codemeadr = str + ' ' + hnr + ' ' + plz + ' ' + stadt + ' ' + land;         
    geocodeme(codemeadr);

    //document.addform.submit();
    alert($('#lat').val() + ' -- ' + $('#long').val());
}
```

my form:

```
....
<input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" />
<input type="hidden" name="long" id="long" />
<a href="javascript:submitme();"> Submit </a>
```

what the problem is that the first time when i click submit, the lat and long are empty(they are not set), but second time i hit the submit, they are set, why is this? why cannot it set the lat and long on the first submit call?

BTW: all those parameters `str`, `hnr`.. they really exist and they are not empty, but this even doesnot matter here..

thanks for help

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328407/store-result-of-google-maps-geocode-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `geocoder.geocode` is asynchronous. You must handle the result in the callback you give it.

This line must be in the callback :

```
alert($('#lat').val() + ' -- ' + $('#long').val());
```

and of course any line you put just at this point can't use the right value.

Comment: thanks, but i am setting in the callback, why it isnot set on the first set?

Comment: You mean you look at the inputs, not the alert ?

Comment: yeah, because without alert i first tried to submit, but then i got error saying that those two inputs are empty. which means that they are not set on time.

Comment: You did understand that you must submit **from** the callback too ?

Comment: oh really? now i understood :D.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronyous callback, that means when you call geocodeme it returns immediately. The callback (function(results, status)) is called after Google replies to your request.

```
...
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                //alert(latitude + ' - ' + longitude);
                $('#lat').val(latitude);
                $('#long').val(longitude);
                document.addform.submit();
...
// call this function on button click not on submit
function submitme(){
    var adres = str + '+' + hnr + '+' + plz + '+' + stadt + '+' + land;
    var codemeadr = str + ' ' + hnr + ' ' + plz + ' ' + stadt + ' ' + land;         
    geocodeme(codemeadr);
// this function returns immediately, even when geocode is not retrieved yet.
    //document.addform.submit();
    alert($('#lat').val() + ' -- ' + $('#long').val());
}
```